# mxnet : how to make prediction using a trained RNN model

Tags: python, recurrent-neural-network, mxnet

I'm testing the RNN model of mxnet. The tutorial [here](http://mxnet.io/tutorials/python/char_lstm.html) does not work and the error message said many functions had been deprecated. I did not find the up-to-date tutorial for RNN.
There are still some examples in the mxnet project. But for RNN, the [examples](https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/blob/master/example/rnn/lstm_bucketing.py) only show how to train a model using training set. They don't show how to use the trained model to make further prediction. The training code is as follows:

```
model.fit(
    train_data          = data_train,
    eval_data           = data_val,
    eval_metric         = mx.metric.Perplexity(invalid_label),
    kvstore             = args.kv_store,
    optimizer           = args.optimizer,
    optimizer_params    = { 'learning_rate': args.lr,
                            'momentum': args.mom,
                            'wd': args.wd },
    initializer         = mx.init.Xavier(factor_type="in", magnitude=2.34),
    num_epoch           = args.num_epochs,
    batch_end_callback  = mx.callback.Speedometer(args.batch_size, args.disp_batches))
```

Does someone know how to use the trained **RNN model** to make inference or prediction?

I must clearify that I'm looking for how to use **RNN model** to make prediction, not CNN or other models.

Thank you very much for helping me!!!

Comment: https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/blob/master/example/rnn/cudnn_lstm_bucketing.py has both train and test code. Does that help?

Comment: No. But the examples in https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/tree/master/python/mxnet/module does help.

Comment: @pfc if you've found the answer, will you answer your own question for others that may need the same help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually model is extends [BaseModel](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/blob/master/python/mxnet/module/base_module.py) class. And BaseModel has [the method `predict`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/blob/master/python/mxnet/module/base_module.py#L300). The method can work with same type that is used by `fit` method: `DataIter` with only one difference, it does not require `train_data`, only `eval_data`. So the actual prediction process can be implemented in a simple way like this:

```
result = mod.predict(dataiter.next)
```